# Input Text not saving on the modal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello Sir/Mam I've been trying to learn to code using html/css mainly pure "javascript" for about a month.

I am making a basic note taking app where you will type in the input field then click "add a note"... It will create a table "text" from the "input field" and then there will be 2 buttons.

Delete note(working fine) and "View more".. The problem I am facing is when I click the "View more".. the modal pops up. Yes its what I wanted But the message its not there...
It seems when I erase what I typed from the input field.. it somehow connects to the modal?
I want to make the "text " from "input" to be on the "modal permanently" so when I create another table the first table-modal still contains the note(whole paragraph)..

while we are at it.. How can I make the paragraph shorter to my table then when I click the  view more.. The modal pops up that contained the whole paragraph?

I Apologize for my not so concise codes.. :) These codes are recycle from my other first two basic app; to-do list & track expense table app(beginners exercise js app) which works perfectly.

These seems to be my problems? I think I need to create another function? not solely depending on childe.innerHTML and appendChild? but I don't know what kind of logic to make. I've tried the push.array but it didn't work or maybe im just wrong. Thanks

```
     const input = document.getElementById("input")
        const modal = document.createElement('div')
        modal.classList.add('modal')
        const child = document.createElement('p')
        child.classList.add('child')
        child.innerHTML = input.value; <---------- it always been equal to the input.value?
        modal.appendChild(child)
        document.body.appendChild(modal)
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Note Taker</title>
  </head>
  <h1>Note Taker App</h1>
  <h2>Add A New Note</h2>
  <body>
    <form class="form">
      <label for="text">Note:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Write your note here ✏️"
        class="inputModal"
        id="input"
        maxlength="1000"
        size="100"
      />
      <button id="outsideButton">Add Note</button>
    </form>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

javascript

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const tbodyEl = document.querySelector("tbody");
const table = document.querySelector("table");

//Function for input field, tables and creating buttons

function onAddNote(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    tbodyEl.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${input}</td><td><button class="modalButton">View More</button><button class="deleteBtn">Delete Note</button></td></tr>`;

 //function for modal show and modal removal   
}
function onButtons(e) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains("deleteBtn")) {
        if (!e.target.classList.contains("modalButton")) {
            return;
        }
        //creating modal and to append it.
        const input = document.getElementById("input")
        const modal = document.createElement('div')
        modal.classList.add('modal')
        const child = document.createElement('p')
        child.classList.add('child')
        child.innerHTML = input.value;
        modal.appendChild(child)
        document.body.appendChild(modal)
        //creating modal-removal & append
        const modalBtn = document.createElement('button')
        modalBtn.innerText = "Close Note";
        modalBtn.style.background = "";
        modalBtn.classList.add('modalBtn')
        modal.appendChild(modalBtn)
        //modal-closing button function
        modalBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.body.removeChild(modal)
        })
    } else {
        //deleting table row
        const btn = e.target;
        btn.closest("tr").remove();
    }
}
// function clicker

table.addEventListener("click", onButtons);
form.addEventListener("submit", onAddNote);
```

Comment: The code you've written doesn't seem like it contains any modal view in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const tbodyEl = document.querySelector("tbody");
const table = document.querySelector("table");

    var data_list = "";

//Function for input field, tables and creating buttons

function onAddNote(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = document.getElementById("input").value;
        data_list = data_list+'\n'+input;
        alert(data_list);
        
    tbodyEl.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${input}</td><td><button class="modalButton">View More</button><button class="deleteBtn">Delete Note</button></td></tr>`;

 //function for modal show and modal removal   
}
function onButtons(e) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains("deleteBtn")) {
        if (!e.target.classList.contains("modalButton")) {
            return;
        }
        //creating modal and to append it.
        const input = document.getElementById("input")
        
        const modal = document.createElement('div')
        modal.classList.add('modal')
        const child = document.createElement('p')
        child.classList.add('child')
        child.innerHTML = data_list;
        modal.appendChild(child)
        document.body.appendChild(modal)
        //creating modal-removal & append
        const modalBtn = document.createElement('button')
        modalBtn.innerText = "Close Note";
        modalBtn.style.background = "";
        modalBtn.classList.add('modalBtn')
        modal.appendChild(modalBtn)
        //modal-closing button function
        modalBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.body.removeChild(modal)
        })
    } else {
        //deleting table row
        const btn = e.target;
        btn.closest("tr").remove();
    }
}
// function clicker

table.addEventListener("click", onButtons);
form.addEventListener("submit", onAddNote);
```

Try to update your javascript as above code and let me know if it works.

I've added a global variable in the code and storing values in it which helps you display all notes at once since your current code displays only the current value of `input` variable.

Comment: thanks sir for your time and I finally figure it out now and how to shortened the input text in the table using ${input}.slice()